# Plotting XY data from newly created shapefile in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile

I know how to plot XY data from a table and then convert to a shapefile, but here I'm trying to assign coordinates from a feature class's attribute table so that it would plot.

I created a point shapefile in ArcCatalog and used the Editor toolbar to enter some records manually. Two of these columns are for latitude and longitude.

How can I have ArcMap plot this layer using these coordinates?

Comment: Use the attribute table the same way as a table and plot the data. Or export attribute table as a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already created the point features, then they have already been positioned and have XY coordinates (even if they are 0,0). You would have to create a new point feature to use the XY information you entered after the fact.

You can avoid having to create a new table by using the '[Make XY Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm)' tool. Use your point as the input, use the appropriate X Y columns, and it will generate a new point feature for you that is in the correct places with the correct records.